# Shopify - remove store title from products page <title> tag

Tags: shopify, title

I am working on a shopify store and I cannot seem to get the code right for removing the store name from only the product pages.

Here is the code:

```
<title>
  {{ page_title }}
  {% if current_tags %}{% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %}&ndash; 
  {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags }}
  {% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; 
  {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}{% endif %}
  {% unless page_title contains shop.name %}
  {% if template != 'article' %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endif %}{% endunless %}
</title>
```

I have tried using an `if` statement above this to change `page_title` to `product_title` but it breaks this code and no titles show up on any other pages.

Also this code prevents the store name from coming up on articles. I tried using the same code but replaced it with 'product' and it did not work!

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain or link me to documentation about the `:` operator? What is going on here: `{{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}`? What is `t` and `page` and `current_page`, and what's `general.meta.page` -- where do those come from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: before and after your shop name add an unless, like this:

```
{% unless template contains 'product' %}
{% unless template contains 'article' %}
 – {{ shop.name }}
{% endunless %}
{% endunless %}
```

Also, you should think about using different lines in your code, makes things more readable. Also, using `contains` instead of `=` is more foolproof, so I took the liberty of changing that for you

Comment: Sorry this solution did not work for me. The products are still having " - [store name]" added to them.

Comment: Can you post your website so I can take a look? I think your in the wrong place. That Title doesn't display at all. Its just for SEO

Comment: Yeah mainly it is for SEO. Just want the shop name out of the title when the product shows up in a google search.

Comment: Found the solution ... an if/else statement. I thought I had tried this without success but it is working now.

{% if template == 'product' %}
  <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
  {% else %}
  <title>{{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %}{% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags }}{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %}{% if template != 'article' %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endif %}{% endunless %}</title>
  {% endif %}

Comment: You should post that as an answer, and please use line breaks to be more readable. Congrats on figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution ... an if/else statement. I thought I had tried this without success but it is working now.

```
{% if template == 'product' %} 
<title>{{ page_title }}</title> 
{% else %} 
<title>{{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %}{% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags }}{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %}{% if template != 'article' %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endif %}{% endunless %}</title> 
{% endif %}
```